# Hi, I am new to php and I cant find a way to make alternate table color in my code. It always show the wrong output that is required for me to follow

Tags: php, html, css

I did the nth child rule in css but it the colors are not alternate. Colors are all the same each rows and columns. My code is a multiplication table with a supposed alternate color. Im having a hard time knowing what I should do to modify or add in my php code to create the desired output (alternate colors in rows and columns in the multiplication table).

Below is my php code:

```
<?php
    for($row=0; $row<=10; $row++){
        echo "<tr>";
        
        for($column=0; $column<=10; $column++){

            if($row==0 && $column==0){
                echo "<td></td>";
            }
                
            else{
                echo "<td>". $row * $column. "</td>";
            }
            
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    ?>
```

CSS code:

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
    padding: 15px;
}

.bold{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, to ask a better question, please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For starters, I think you almost certainly want to be closing the `<tr>` inside your outer `foreach` loop!

Comment: And then, just to be certain, are there `<table>` and `</table>` output somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget to use the `<table>` tag and your CSS address it from the table.

```
<?php
   echo "<table>";
    for($row=0; $row<=10; $row++){
        echo "<tr>";
        
        for($column=0; $column<=10; $column++){

            if($row==0 && $column==0){
                echo "<td></td>";
            }
                
            else{
                echo "<td>". $row * $column. "</td>";
            }
            
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: I noticed what went wrong in my code, seems that I have forgotten a few. Thank you! MY code went well according to the required output already.